# Mongo keeps using the wrong id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to query my local MongoDB server but i can't seem to extract the "id" field from the data.

One piece of data looks like this:

```
{
    artist: "Phil Saunders",
    attack: 3,
    cardClass: "PRIEST",
    collectible: true,
    cost: 5,
    dbfId: 42046,
    elite: true,
    flavor:
      "Arise, fair sun, and kill my envious foes. They don't have a legendary as beautiful as you.",
    health: 5,
    id: "UNG_963",
    mechanics: ["TRIGGER_VISUAL"],
    name: "Lyra the Sunshard",
    race: "ELEMENTAL",
    rarity: "LEGENDARY",
    set: "UNGORO",
    text: "Whenever you cast a spell, add a random Priest spell to your hand.",
    type: "MINION",
  }
```

And the query itself looks like this:

```
db.collection("cards")
      .find({
        cardClass: cardClass,
        rarity: cardRarity,
      })
      .project({ name: 1, id: 1 })
      .toArray((err, results) => {
        if (err || Object.keys(results).length === 0) {
          res
            .status(404)
            .send("Could not find cards with given search criteria")
        } else {
          res.status(200).send(results)
        }
      })
```

Why does it keep giving me _id instead of id? It returns objects like this:

```
{_id: "605b3c2406f91826e03d9135", name: "Ironwood Golem"}
```

That is not the id I want. How do I get the original one?

Comment: Because, apparently, `id` is missing from the data set you selected while `_id` is a completely different field and will appear by default unless explicitly suppressed with `{ name: true, id: true, _id: false }`.

Comment: But `id` is in the data set I selected, it's in every single object. I also tried that code and now it ONLY returns name.

Comment: Yes, each 'card' looks like above

Comment: I would comment out `project` altogether and console out the result to make double sure the `id` field is actually there.

Comment: Ok i did that and it seems like a bunch of fields are actually missing

Comment: Your returned document doesn't match the document that you supposedly are querying.

Comment: Yeah because i'm filtering out fields with `.project`

Comment: @IsaiahG A bunch of fields missing including the `id` field?

Comment: Yes. Could there be some sort of limit to the amount of fields that get returned?

Comment: NVM, i'm writing this for a project and the fields get removed in the given code. Overlooked that. Whoops. Thanks for your concern though.

Comment: Not without `project`. You can also log into through you terminal and check the original by running `db.your_collection.find({cardClass: "xx", rarity: "xx"}).pretty()` to see what's strored.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [mongodb documentation][1] the The _id field is included in the returned documents by default unless you explicitly specify _id: 0 in the projection to suppress the field.
[1]: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/